# How to disable mobile back button

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I am doing a mobile application using Jquery Mobile. In my application first page is the login page and second is the list page. I have a problem that when the mobile back button is clicked from the second page it going to the login page, which can not be happend. So how can I disable mobile back button only in second page?

Comment: I would only display a login screen if the user is not logged in (for every url) otherwise display the page that corresponds to the requested url. Or generally speaking: show the content corresponding to the login state.

Comment: Please specify, browser back button or page back button.

Answer (score 3):

You can't or, better said, you shouldn't. The mobile "back" button is like the Browser "back" button, both are a feature of the navigator. Hack it to disable it's function through javascript could be considered a bad practice, IMO.

**EDIT**

Suggested way to implement the access check logic, as proposed by [t.niese](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1960455/t-niese) on comments

1. **Do NOT** have a login page url, i.e. `http://some.x/login`.
2. On each page which requires the user to be logged, i.e. `http://some.x/list/page`, perform the access check.
3. If the user **is NOT** logged in, just respond [with the corresponding status code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2839585/what-is-correct-http-status-code-when-redirecting-to-a-login-page) in the header and display the login screen there. Else case, display the requested page.

This way the login page acts transparently, and isn't stored on the history. You should be able to go back without seen the login form anymore.

Comment: `if the user is logged in, redirect to the list page` is a _bad_ idea in this situation: User is on another page and opens the login page, then the user does a login, and is redirected to the list page. If the user now want to go back with the back button to the page before the login screen, it would not be possible (if the login page is still in history), because at the time the users gets to this page he is redirected to the list page again.

Comment: That's correct, could be nice to hear your suggestion. Anyway i assumed the following flow: request the URL of the list page => access check => decission. This way the login page's URL is never stored on history.

Comment: I prefere not to have a `http://www.some.tdl/login/page`. If a request is done to `http://www.some.tdl/a/page` and user is not logged in just respond with the corresponding status code in the header and display a login screen. If the user does a login on that page, it is easy to redirect back to that page, and the user is logged in (or back on the page where his login session ended due his own logout or session timeout due e.g. lunch break or meeting)

Comment: you're right, sure! In addition to your comment, doing this way the login page is never stored on the history

Comment: @t.niese I edited the answer to add your suggestion as i think it's more correct than mine.

Answer (score -2):

You can modify the history of the browser to correct it. Look for https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history